# baseballreference.com reading the tables for player statistics (roger maris)

Tags: baseball

I have been figuring out this site ok but I do not really understand why there are 3 entries for maris in 1958. If I want to figure out his home runs that season. Should I just add up all the 1958 or would there be a particular reason it has been entered 3 times like that instead of once for the whole year?

[image: Roger Maris 1958 stats]

Here is the link http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/m/marisro01.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean 1958, and if you look at the column named "Tm", notice that of of the three rows for 1958 has "TOT" in that column.

That row contains the totals of the other two rows, so no need to do any extra work.

Note, too, that the stats grid has some power built into it where one can click on two rows that represent the beginning and end of a period to examine, and a pop-up will display the totals for that period.

For example, click on the first and last rows of Maris' stats, and the pop-up will produce totals that match the Career Totals row, i.e. the 1958 rows for CLE and KCA are not included in the totals because they're already accounted for by the 1958 TOT row.  In fact, clear the grid of the previous selection and try clicking on either of the rows that doesn't contain the totals and notice that the row isn't highlighted.  This is likely to prevent one from trying to include all three  1958 rows in one of these ad hoc summaries.  (Note: it also seems that clicking on one of those rows I've described short-circuits that summarization function completely, at least in Chrome on a Mac.)